# How to write a test case for Touchable highlight onpress function in react-native using jest and enzyme

Tags: react-native, tdd, jestjs, jest-fetch-mock

So,Here is my code for touchablehighlight,I used simulate for calling a  onpress function  but is is not working can anyone help me .

```
 <TouchableHighlight style={styles.touchableButtonview} 
      onPress = {(this.authUser.bind(this))}>
      <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Sign in</Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
```